# Why the Django admin interface didn't appear?

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie for django.

I'm trying to run a sample according to a book about django.

I've added "class Admin" to my model classes, however, in the django admin interface, I can only see the "Users", "Groups" and "Sites", none of my model classes appear.

There is no error or warning information, so I don't know what happened and what shall I do next.

Any help?

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website=models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Admin:
        pass

class Author(models.Model):
    salutation=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email=models.EmailField()
    headshot=models.ImageField(upload_to='/tmp')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Admin:
        pass

class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    authors=models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher=models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: The book you are reading isn't updated for the current version of django. You should go through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: I have some experience but am still new to Django and seriously just ran into the same problem. I think we're reading the same book. After reading the answer below to create the 'admin.py' and register the models that resolved my issue too. :) Great question by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do three things to be able to edit your models via admin site:

1. Create file 'admin.py' in your app directory with code (look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects):

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from your_app.models import Publisher, Author, Book

   admin.site.register(Author)
   admin.site.register(Publisher)
   admin.site.register(Book)
   ```
2. In your urls.py add the following (look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf):

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
   from django.contrib import admin

   admin.autodiscover()

   urlpatterns = patterns('',
       (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
       # your urls goes here
   )
   ```
3. Be sure, that your settings.py satisfy following (look https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overview):

   ```
   TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
       'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
       #other context processors
   )

   MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
       # other middleware
   )

   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       # other apps
   )
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You should create admin.py and follow by below code

```
from xxxxx.models import Publisher
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book)
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the part about [registering the models with the admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin).

Answer (score 1):

What you did there is not how it's really done. The right way is to have models in `models.py` and admin classes in `admin.py`.

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website=models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Author(models.Model):
    salutation=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email=models.EmailField()
    headshot=models.ImageField(upload_to='/tmp')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class Book(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    authors=models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher=models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Author, Publisher


class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class PublisherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
admin.site.register(Publisher, PublisherAdmin)
```

Also, if your admin classes are empty with just `pass` in them, you can omit them all together, so you end up like this:

`admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Author, Publisher


admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Publisher)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using old methods to declare models which should appear in admin interface. This methods are obsolete now.
Please consider to manuals and make yourself clear of which version of django you use. And how to get what you want.